# VBA code for "Text to Column - Fixed Width" - loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, fixed-width, text-to-column

I am looking to find a way to make my code more simple, more efficient and create a loop that will be running until it reaches the last character.

First, I am getting data that always looks like the example below and should be pasted in a row (usually cell A1):

7666976-15012020092737.pdf; 7665725-15012020092757.pdf; 7669477-15012020092833.pdf; 7669483-15012020092844.pdf; 7669492-15012020092857.pdf; 7669494-15012020092910.pdf; 7669495-15012020092921.pdf; 7669546-15012020092933.pdf; 7669548-15012020092953.pdf; 7669548-15012020093010.pdf; 7669551-15012020093047.pdf; 7669552-15012020093111.pdf; 7669554-15012020093138.pdf; 7669557-15012020093205.pdf; 7669558-15012020093245.pdf; 7669563-15012020093311.pdf; 7672877-15012020093344.pdf; 7672879-15012020093401.pdf; 7672881-15012020093415.pdf; 7672882-15012020093425.pdf; 7672884-15012020093437.pdf

Then I am splitting it by using the *Text to Column - Fixed Width* option in Excel. The length of every fragment should be always 28 characters.

So far I managed to create the code below that is working, but I believe that it might be better - for example, if there are 1000 characters I should keep adding Array(728,1), Array (756,1), etc. to the code.

```
Range("A1").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("S1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(56, 1), Array(84, 1), Array(112, 1), _
        Array(140, 1), Array(168, 1), Array(196, 1), Array(224, 1), Array(252, 1), Array(280, 1), _
        Array(308, 1), Array(336, 1), Array(364, 1), Array(392, 1), Array(420, 1), Array(448, 1), _
        Array(476, 1), Array(504, 1), Array(532, 1), Array(560, 1), Array(588, 1), Array(616, 1), _
        Array(642, 1), Array(672, 1), Array(700, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

How could it be improved?

Comment: You could just use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) here to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use both delimiters (i.e., semicolon & space).

Try this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST")
    .Cells(1).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("S1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Space:=True
    .Range("S1").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: Ah, right, that's even cooler. Never had to look into `ConsecutiveDelimiter` but that's great to know.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you might just use the [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's codename
    arr = Split(.Range("A1").Value, "; ")
    .Range("S1").Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
End With

End Sub
```

Although [`Range.TextToColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) isn't bad either. Because you actually wanted to delimit by `;`  instead of just a semi-colon there were <strike>two</strike>* options:

- Remove the spaces/semicolons from your original string first:

  ```
    Sub Test

    With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's codename
        .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A1").Replace(" ", "")
        .Range("A1").TextToColumns .Range("S1"), DataType:=1, Semicolon:=True
    End With

    End Sub
  ```
- Use `Application.Trim` right after your code has run to remove leading/trailing spaces from all cells at once:

  ```
    Sub Test

    With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's codename
        .Range("A1").TextToColumns .Range("S1"), DataType:=1, Semicolon:=True
        Application.Trim (.Rows(1))
    End With

    End Sub
  ```

The latter one won't affect your `A1` value, so you might want to go for that.

---

***Note:** Setting `ConsecutiveDelimiter` to `True` makes for use of multiple delimiters as per [EEM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754094/9758194).

Comment: I figured it could be done simply with `TextToColumns` ;-)