# Delimiting text to columns down to the last row is not working in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delimit my time text to the separate columns:

[image]

I used the following approach:

*[VBA code for "Text to Column - Fixed Width" - loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752905/vba-code-for-text-to-column-fixed-width-loop)*

But I don't know how to apply it for the column range down to the last row.

My code looks like this:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

lRow = wks.Range("D" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With wks
   .Cells(4, lRow).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("S1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
      Semicolon:=True, Space:=False
   .Range("S1").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
 End With
```

And I am getting an error:

> No data was selected to parse.

How can I make it work with my range of cells?

Answer (score 0):

When performing `text-to-column` in VBA, you do not need to set the `last row` for the range. Just set it until end of the row will do. Please perform a test with the following by replacing `cells with column` only:

```
With wks
   .Columns("D:D").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("S1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
      Semicolon:=True, Space:=False
   .Range("S1").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
 End With
```

Or:

```
wks.range("D4:D").TextToColumns ....
```

Comment: Still almost the same... It seems to work, but my Excel is completely frozen. I just had a few records delimited randomly across the range and I couldn't even shut down my Excel afterwards, It does work if I have space, but it can't definitely go with the semicolon.

Comment: Normally setting to end of the row won't affect the speed performance, do you make a improper looping and cause `infinitely loop`? You will only need set to `last row` when you are perform looping checking, however `text-to-column` does not apply looping